# VoiceOver accessibility semantics for Autocomplete widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my app, I use `Autocomplete` to display some autocomplete results when my user type in a `Textfield`, everything does work the way I intended.

My problem comes with the support of screenreaders (VoiceOver/Talkback) accessibility.

Using VoiceOver/Talkback, I'm unable to tap on the dropdown menu created by the `Autocomplete` widget. I therefore cannot listen to the name of my results.

Meaning that in the screenshot below, if I tap on "Apple", VoiceOver should read "Apple", if I double tap on "Apple" it should select Apple (in the callback `onSelected`).   Unfortuntely, I apparently cannot tap/select any data in the dropdown menu using VoiceOver/Talkback.

The problem occurs -ONLY- when the `Autocomplete` widget is in `showGeneralDialog`

[image]

I created a Dartpad at this URL explaining in detail how to activate VoiceOver/Talkback and my problem in a more "simple" way.
https://dartpad.dev/?id=202fd4fc050079a64f50794415f2600d.

You can also check the code of that Dartpad at the following URL: https://gist.github.com/BLKKKBVSIK/202fd4fc050079a64f50794415f2600d